# Make glowing effect around the text box while active

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Make glowing effect around the text box while placing the cursor inside the textbox.
For example : just place the cursor inside the search textbox in our stackoverflow.com.

Its because of css, but i dont know how to achieve it.. Please help me.

Comment: Placing the cursor in the search @ stackoverflow does not produce the visual you are describing.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think all browsers on my Mac OS X do that for all edit boxes. It's the system behavior.

Comment: I would use an animated gif and use my css to get the text box inside the animated gif. Try this link for a tutorial on css overlays: http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/overlay/ You will also want to use javascript to either hide or change the image when the text box gains and loses focus.

Comment: no, while using google chrome its showing a golden color border

Comment: its not a problem, i just want to change the border color while placing the cursor inside the text box. is it possible

Comment: yes, i can understand now. But is it possible to do like that using css and javascript

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While the effect you observe on the stackoverflow search box is probably browser specific (e.g. Google Chrome) there is a way to achieve what you want using the CSS [`:focus`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes) pseudo class:

```
#foo:focus { border: 2px solid red; }
```

```
<input id="foo" type="text"/>
```

Comment: The outline property is more appropriate here than setting the border.

Comment: You're right, the outline property is more appropriate here. It doesn't work in IE however but neither does the :focus pseudo class..

Answer (score 18):

Instead of outlines, the `box-shadow` property achieves a very smooth, nice effect of any text field:

```
field {
    border-color: #dbdbdb;
}

field:focus { /* When you click on the field... */
    border-color: #6EA2DE;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #6EA2DE;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/beakr/z9RBq/) I once made myself showing the above code with a transition fade effect.

Answer (score 3):

Outline property

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_outline.asp

If you want it to appear when clicking on a text box:

```
input:focus { outline: /* whatever */ }
```

IE7 doesn't support the :focus selector, but you can use jQuery:

```
$("input").focus(function () {
     $(this).css('outline','yellow solid thin');
});
```

Comment: yes, but in need this same, while cursor inside the textbox, if its comes out then it will act as normal textbox

Comment: Are you saying that you want the outline whether the focus is on the textbox or not? You can use the input selector for that (instead of input:focus).

Comment: IE7 doesn't support the :focus selector, I edited my answer to include a jQuery workaround.

Comment: IE7 doesn't support outline either

Answer (score 2):

Obviously outline isn't supported by IE7 and even if it was I doubt it would "glow". You need to do this with a custom background image or something. There's an example of doing that here:

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/CSS/Q_24084560.html

BTW: You say "border color". A border is not an outline. You can just use:

```
<input onfocus="this.style.border='2px solid yellow'">
```

You can do it with the CSS :focus pseudo-class but chances are IE6/7 doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

Code-

```
input[type=text], textarea {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  outline: none;
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}

input[type=text]:focus, textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
}
```

Demo- http://www.labshab.com/submit-guest-posts/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bootstrap you can use

```
class="form-control"
```