# Text field "glowing" effect like Twitter and Tumblr login pages?

Tags: html, css, textbox, stylesheet

What's the best way to achieve a glowing effect when focusing on a text field in HTML? Can it be done with CSS alone, or does it involve images? Check out the login pages for Twitter and Tumblr for working examples.

[image]

Comment: Just inspect the element, the css is all there. on `:focus` apply `border: 1px solid #56B4EF;` and `box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.05),0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS - Focus login fields just like twitter with only CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282678/css-focus-login-fields-just-like-twitter-with-only-css)

Comment: @Pumbaa80, not a duplicate, that question is in regards to the functional aspects of Twitter's login text fields, not their appearance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the `:focus` pseudo-class, `border` and `box-shadow`:

```css
.text:focus {
    border: 1px solid #07c;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #07c;
}
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/5TwW8/)

Oh, and [here's my favorite combination](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/5TwW8/2/).

Answer (score 2):

I would approach it by using a CSS box shadow and then set the color to blue rather than grey / black.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I'm no CSS expert!

Comment: A few other people have posted examples. But, if you are no expert you can have a play around with this website. It's great for creating little css bits such as a box shadow.

http://css3generator.com/

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
#form1:focus { border: 2px solid blue; }
```

HTML:

```
<input id="form1" type="text"/>
```

Other ways that I found:

[Make glowing effect around the text box while active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996371/make-glowing-effect-around-the-text-box-while-active)

Answer (score 0):

use the `focus`

**sample:** http://jsfiddle.net/uday99/kFGmC/23/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using cross-browser approaches:

```
.active-field, .selector-for-field:focus {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgb(34%, 71%, 94%);
 -khtml-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgb(34%, 71%, 94%);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgb(34%, 71%, 94%);
 -o-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgb(34%, 71%, 94%);
 box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgb(34%, 71%, 94%);
 border:1px solid rgb(34%, 71%, 94%);
}
```

Then add this class to the highlighted field on click or focus, etc as needed.

You can also get the IE specific ones in there if needed.

Comment: Prefixed versions of `box-shadow` are outdated; you shouldn't use them.

Comment: I disagree - I am still seeing old versions of browsers using our sites so these are still in play.  I'd suggest you benchmark the need against your own visitors rather than take the above advice without checking.

Answer (score 0):

Either images, or CSS Box shadow
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/